# esp32 cam text recognition

Tags: image, esp32, arduino-esp32

how to extract text from an image by using esp32 cam image processing.

I tried this and extract live text from esp32 cam  but can not from image (camera captured photo).
I need help to make this project and extract text after taking an image from esp32.